# Hiding HTML Elements in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to hide a HTML DIV element in React. I'm checking to see if the user is on Mac or Window. If they're on windows I want to hide the DIV as its specifically for Mac.

Below is the code I'm executing in my lights.component.jsx above the render()

```
if (process.platform = 'win32') {
  let x = document.getElementById('macButtons').style.display = "none"

} else if (process.platform = 'darwin') {
document.getElementById('macButtons').style.display = "block"
}
```

The code above is not executing. What can I do to make this work?

Edit: Souce code: https://sourceb.in/424e012881.jsx

Comment: Are you using class based components or functional components?

Comment: Could we see your entire code? It's unclear what the context is here. For example, is this logic somewhere inside a component? If so, why not just conditionally render the component in question based on the process platform?

Comment: Have you tried using comparison operators in your if blocks? Right now your code is showing assignment in the if() which will never make the check. try using == or ===

Comment: This is my source code: sourceb.in/424e012881.jsx Basically I'm trying to make it so that the 'macButtons' DIV only displays when the OS is Mac and is hidden when its any other OS

Comment: React runs in the **browser** so you can't use the Node.js specific `process` API!

Comment: What can I use then instead of `process`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks more like the if() blocks aren't working because of the assignment operator `=` instead of comparison `==` or `===`.
You could filter the components in the JSX when you're getting the right platform like so:

```
...
<div>
    {process.platform === 'darwin' ? <ServerBrowser/> : null}
</div>
...
```

---

If you're intending on this to be used in a browser as a web application then you'll want to look into the [window.navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator) object for your comparison. `window.navigator.platform` will probably give you what you need. It's going to be your best bet from the front-end as you can't access the actually machine using the browser to know the OS.

That said, if you're using node + electron (or something else locally) then this should help:

```
    <div className="macButtons" style={{ display: process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
```

Changing the display to none when you fail to meet the 'darwin' requirement should hide the html. Alternatively you can try using a wrapper component that renders your `ServerBrowser` like in the first example (which has been updated.)

You could also try with the navigator object too:

```
<div className="macButtons" style={{ window.navigator.platform !== 'Win32' ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
```

Comment: This is my source code: https://sourceb.in/424e012881.jsx

Basically I'm trying to make it so that the 'macButtons' DIV only displays when the OS is Mac and is hidden when its any other OS.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using NodeJS and Electron for this App and it will be for both desktop and browser

Comment: @Vidsify Ok good to know, then you should be able to use the process object, in which case have you tried changing the display to be none?

Comment: I've tried the one for Node + electron as you've mentioned above. Works perfectly fine on windows, so it hides the DIV. However, it is also hiding it on Mac

Comment: Have you tried seeing what the exact spelling is from the console? Try running a node repl and see what process.platform gives you. Then update your ternary operator with what it shows for mac.

Comment: So I ran a console.log(process.platform) and it returned undefined. So I did console.log(window.navigator.platform) and it returned MacIntel

Comment: Hmm, well that's odd if it was in a native console. Try using  the navigator object then, that'll work in browser too anyways. e.g. style={{ display: window.navigator.platform === 'MacIntel' ? 'block' : 'none' }}

Answer (score 2):

You should not be operating with DOM elements on React, instead just use something like:

```js
<div 
  id="light-red" 
  style={{ display : process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'block' : 'inline' }}
```

Comment: This isn't working. I've tried doing it like that but it still displays on Windows. My source code is posted above